# "./main: not found" (C++, RP 3/B, Geany IDE)

Tags: c++, geany

I'm attempting to write a simple program that calls a function written in a pair of Header and CPP files.

I'm doing this on a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B, and the Geany IDE v1.37.1.

Compile Command:

```
g++ -Wall -c "%f" -c test.cpp
```

Build Command:

```
g++ -Wall -o "%e" "%f" -o test test.cpp
```

`main.cpp`:

```
#include "test.h"

int main()
{
    test_function();
    
    return 0;
}
```

`test.h`:

```
#ifndef _test_h_
#define _test_h_

#include <iostream>

void test_function();

#endif
```

`test.cpp`:

```
#include "test.h"

void test_function()
{
    std::cout << "hello world";
}
```

The code above compiles & builds fine, however attempting to run it yields the following error:

```
./main: not found

(program exited with code: 127)
```

Perhaps I am messing something up with the Compile & Build Commands?

Thank you for reading my post, any guidance is apprecaited!

Comment: Your two build commands don't make sense. If you do a two-stage build with separate compilation and linking steps only the first command should be taking the `.cpp` file as input and there should be one command for each `.cpp` file. I don't now what the `%` placeholders refer to in your IDE, but in the second command you should be passing the object files (`.o`) files for linking. You also give the `-o` option twice which doesn't make sense. Repeating `-c` in the first command is also pointless.

Comment: If you do compilation and linking in one step then there should only be the second command and it should take all `.cpp` files as input. (And there should be only one `-o` option).

Comment: You're right, these compilation commands I was using appear to not be working correctly. I'm a bit confused on how I'm supposed to write them. I have 2 Command options, one for `Compile` and one for the `Build`. The differing argument between the two appear to be `-c` and `-o`. I notice that the `Build` command takes two arguments, one for the name of the program, and one for the supposed input files.

Comment: If I put all the cpp files in the `Compile` command (`g++ -Wall -c "test.cpp"`), I get an error  for multiple redefinitions of the function in `test.cpp`. Is there a way to go around that?

Comment: What are the placeholders like `"%f"` representing? Maybe they are already the file names and it is wrong to add any manually at all? This should be explained somewhere in the documentation for your IDE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice the compile command:

`-o test`

This means that the output binary will be `test`, so you can execute the application in your terminal or shell via `./test`.

Comment: What does it mean "call it via ./test"? You mean rename my "main" function to "test"?

Comment: @Runsva No, function name is fine. 'attempting to run' - how do you attempt to run it? Normally, you'd run it as `./test`. Alternatively, if the IDE is running it for you, you might use `-o main` instead of `-o test`.

Comment: ***What does it mean "call it via ./test"? You mean rename my "main" function to "test"?*** No its not the name of the function called. Its the name of the executable program. Since this is confusing to you it appears that you need to learn a little more about your terminal and how to run programs from the terminal in your OS. Here is a link: [https://magpi.raspberrypi.com/articles/terminal-help](https://magpi.raspberrypi.com/articles/terminal-help)

Comment: Also here: [https://www.linuxfordevices.com/tutorials/linux/build-execute-cpp-code-in-terminal](https://www.linuxfordevices.com/tutorials/linux/build-execute-cpp-code-in-terminal)

Comment: Ok thanks for your comments. It appears that my problem is actually the lack of cpp files in the `Compile` command. How would I properly include my cpp files, so I don't get multiple redefinitions of the function?

Comment: You probably want to ask a brand new question about the new problem. That is a different topic than this one which is answered. For that new question you will have to add the exact details of how you built your code.

Comment: Ok got it, thanks for the feedback! This answer solved the problem of the incorrect output executable being called.